# Missing iOS Simulator on Alexandria

Tags: delphi, ios-simulator, delphi-11-alexandria

I am having some strange occurrence.
In Delphi 11 IDE - on a new project I am missing iOS Simulator as a Target Platform option.

- Is there a way to bring it back, or it is permanently gone as an option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The situation is caused by compiler support.

Since Delphi XE2-Alexandria support iOS Simulator (32 bit, Intel CPU) only, we could not get Delphi 11 (Alexandria) to get iOS Simulator SDK nor run on iOS Simulator from XCode iOS Simulator later than 10.

Because the iOS Simulator 11 and later does not provide 32 bit anymore, we need to download 32 bit iOS Simulator to enable the option.

However, if your MacBook Air/Pro/iMac had upgraded to 64 bit Only macOS, e.g., macOS 10.15/11/12, you cannot install previous Xcode anymore (even you get the Xcode from developer.apple.com), and the iOS Simulator option will disappear.

As I know, this is a struggle. To maintain iOS Simulator 64 bit Intel support? or Jumping into macOS Apple Silicon only? There is no final decision in EMBT.

Although I hope that EMBT can support Intel 64bit iOS Simulator and M1 64 bit iOS Simulator, that is still a difficult call.

Comment: instead of having full debug support, could just support deploy to the 64-bit iOS simulator for easy trying of an app (see how it appears), especially with remote Mac targets this is important instead of having to also find an iOS device and then get usb remoting software (see https://www.macminivault.com/sharing-a-usb-device-with-a-remote-mac/)

Comment: I thought so, and reflect this point of view to embarcadero 2 weeks ago, and I believe that they will consider the importance to speed up the iOS simulator support soon.

Answer (score 2):

Found the reason.
In MacOS must be download iOS simulator a bit lower version.
In my case version 13 worked well.
Once done - at least 1 project should be created in XCode and run on the simulator.
Then restarting the PAServer and the simulator will automatically appear on the Target platforms.

Comment: Hi, Yanakiev,

Would you please share the information about the MacOS version, Xcode version?

I tried Alexandria 11.1 patch 1 with Win11, MacOS 12.3.1 and Xcode 13.3.1 with iOS simulator 13, 15, PAServer 22.0.

The iOS Simulator option could not appear in the Target platform, nor in the SDK manager. I could not add iOS Simulator SDK either...

Comment: I am not using 11.1 patch 1. i'm on the original alexandria, under Win 10, with mac os 11.1, xcode from 5 months ago.

Comment: No wonder, mac os 11.1 and xcode 12/11 is the key factor. The combination of Delphi, PAServer, MacOS, Xcode will cause if the iOS Simulator could work. Once you upgrade macOS to 12, Xcode will be asked to upgrade, and the workaround will not work anymore.

Answer (score 2):

all,

It's Aug 11, 2022. As Macro Cantu mentioned in his [blog in embarcadero](https://blogs.embarcadero.com/delphi-ios-simulator-support-in-the-coming-version-of-rad-studio/), the iOS simulator support will be back soon.

The feature will support for Mac machine with M1/M2 CPU (not available for Intel CPU). As I know, that's relative to compiler, since M1/M2 CPU is 64 bit Arm architecture, identical to iOS device, the simulator on M1/M2 CPU can use the compiled image for iOS Device.

But if the feature supports Intel CPU, it will take much more time, hence the feature does not support Intel CPU.